# Why does my figure not render when I change the name of variable in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The following code works fine and is taken from https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-prerequisites.html . But a peculiar thing happens when I change the value of the variable canvas to something else like canvas2. Why is that?

```
<html>
    <script type = "module">
    import * as THREE from "../three.js/build/three.module.js"
    function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});  
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
main();
    </script>
    <body>
         <canvas id="c" width="1200" height="600"  >
        </canvas>
    </body> 
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

For instance, if I change, the lines involving canvas as the following, the code doesn't work

```
const somethingElse = document.querySelector('#c');
   const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({somethingElse});
```

Comment: Value or name of the variable?

Comment: @prisoner849 Name of variable, if i do the following, it doesn't work:

   `const somethingElse = document.querySelector('#c');`

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this: `const somethingElse = document.querySelector('#c'); const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: somethingElse});` ?

Comment: @prisoner849 you are right

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, {something} is a shortcut for {something:something} , which I had missed, so there you have it.